# How to change p:panel border color via js?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How can I change the border color via js ?

The following example is working only when the user is pressing the button meaning the color will change back to the default one.

```
  <h:panelGroup>
            <p:commandButton 
                actionListener="#{bean.run}"
                value="Execute"
                update="panel1,panel2" 
                icon="ui-icon-shuffle"
                onclick="document.getElementById('panel2').style.borderColor='#00FF00'">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid> 
</p:panel>
<p:messages id="msg" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true"/>  
<f:verbatim><br/></f:verbatim>
<p:panel id="panel2" style="border-color: #FFFFFF">
    <p:inputTextarea value="#{bean.output}" readonly="true" rows="2" rendered="#{bean.renderOutput}"/>
</p:panel>
```

How can I change permanently the panel2 border color ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *permanently*? You seem to be setting it. Do you mean you want to set the style back upon some event?

Comment: The color of the pane will be change only when I press the button otherwise the panel will use the default color

Comment: Uh, just replace `#FFFFFF` by `#00FF00`? I am confused as this is a too obvious answer which you've basically already prepared/hinted by yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding basically what I want to do is to render the inputTextArea now since the panel default color is blue I need to find some workaround in order to remove it from the screen
so the reason for the #FFFFFF is just for the first time – hope I am clear :)